# Converting a sequence of ppm images to video with python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, video, gimp, ppm

I'm trying to make a video out of ppm images using IPython (python 2.7).

I wrote this code :

```
import cv2
import glob

img1 = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Joseph/image0.ppm')
height, width, layers = img1.shape

video1 = cv2.VideoWriter('video1.avi', -1, 1, (width, height))

filenames = glob.glob('C:/Users/Joseph/*.ppm')
for filename in filenames:
    print(filename)
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    video1.write(img)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video1.release()
```

The video is created but is empty `size=0B` and it cannot be opened.

There is no error message.

I suspect the problem is the writing of the location, since `print(filename)` yields :

> C:/Users/Joseph\image0.ppm
>
> C:/Users/Joseph\image1.ppm
>
> C:/Users/Joseph\image2.ppm
>
> C:/Users/Joseph\image2.ppm

instead of what I had expected : `C:/Users/Joseph/image0.ppm`

Could you help me please?

**EDIT:** The type of file is `type: GIMP 2.10.14 (.ppm)`. Could the issue be connected to this type of ppm ?

**EDIT 2:** It seems that the issue is not connected directly to `.ppm`.

Indeed, I tried (taking into account the answer of Rotem) :

```
import cv2
import glob

i = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Joseph/image0.ppm')
cv2.imwrite('C:/Users/Joseph/image.jpg',i)


img1 = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Joseph/image.jpg')
height, width, layers = img1.shape

# Set FOURCC code to '24BG' - '24BG' is used for creating uncompressed raw video
video1 = cv2.VideoWriter('video1.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('D','I','B',' '), 1, (width, height))

filenames = glob.glob('C:/Users/Joseph/*.ppm')

try:
    for filename in filenames:
        print(filename)
        img = cv2.imread(filename)
        cv2.imwrite('C:/Users/Joseph/a.jpg',img)
        img=cv2.imread('C:/Users/Joseph/a.jpg')
        # Display input image for debugging
        cv2.imshow('img', img)
        cv2.waitKey(1000)
        video1.write(img)
except:
     print('An error occurred.')

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video1.release()
```

And it doesn't work either. And I don't get any image displayed.

so it seems that it's an error in my cv2 for video. The jpg is well created.

**EDIT : The solution.**

In the spirit of the answer of rotem, I tried :  `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G')` and it worked !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple reasons for getting an empty video file, but the path looks correct.

In Windows system `C:/Users/Joseph\image0.ppm` and `C:/Users/Joseph/image0.ppm` are the same.

- Manually delete `video1.avi` file, just to make sure the file is not locked.

I think the issue involved [video **codec**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_codec), but I can't be sure about it.

in the command `video1 = cv2.VideoWriter('video1.avi', -1, 1, (width, height))`, the second parameter is a [FOURCC](https://www.fourcc.org/) code that selects the video codec for the video encoder.
When setting the value to `-1`, a dialog box is opened letting you select the codec.
In older versions of OpenCV it's not always working.

Try setting the FOURCC to `'DIB '`, applies "Basic Windows bitmap format".
Use it for creating raw (uncompressed) AVI video file.

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import glob

img1 = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Joseph/image0.ppm')
height, width, layers = img1.shape

# Set FOURCC code to '24BG' - '24BG' is used for creating uncompressed raw video
video1 = cv2.VideoWriter('video1.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('D','I','B',' '), 1, (width, height))

filenames = glob.glob('*.ppm')

try:
    for filename in filenames:
        print(filename)
        img = cv2.imread(filename)

        # Display input image for debugging
        cv2.imshow('img', img)
        cv2.waitKey(1000)

        video1.write(img)
except:
     print('An error occurred.')

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video1.release()
```

- I added `cv2.imshow('img', img)` to help you debugging the problem, in case it's not a codec issue.
- Make sure you are not getting any exceptions.

Please let me no if my answer solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks ! But it still doesn't work. The strange thing is that I also tried on another computer and it doesn't work either. But I can view well the images with GIMP. I also edited  an edit about GIMP, since I just thought about that.

Comment: I forgot to say that there is also no error messages

Comment: Try: Save few images in PNG format (use save as in GIMP). Just to make sure the issue is not the PPM format, try to create the video from PNGs.

Comment: You can also try using Python 3, with newer version of OpenCV. The same code is compatible to Python 3